# How to calculate the total lenght of a series of arc lenghts when the angle changes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem states the following

> The figure shows a small iron sphere hanging from a spoon-like
>   structure by a flexible wire labeled as $\textrm{QH}$. The sphere is
>   pushed in the indicated direction in such a way that the wire always
>   stays taut so that the sphere reaches $\textrm{MN}$. Calculate the
>   length traveled by the sphere. Consider these lengths
>   $\textrm{MN=NP=PQ=9 inch}$.

The figure is attached below:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

What I did to tackle this problem was to separate the distance traveled by the hanging sphere into three different arc segments to which I labeled as $\textrm{L}_{1}$, $\textrm{L}_{2}$, $\textrm{L}_{3}$. See figure below of the proposed solution

[image: Sketch of the proposed solution]

Taken into consideration I noticed that the angle of all circle segments were $60^\circ$, $30^\circ$ and again $60^\circ$.

However for this to be consistent I took the fact that the gravity acting on the iron sphere would make that part such as a leveling instrument and therefore the angle on $\angle HQ\textrm{wall on the right side}=90^\circ$. From then on I calculated them as this way:

$$\textrm{I define the point where the structure is fixed on the right wall=R}$$

$$\angle PQR = 150^\circ$$
$$\angle PQH= 150^\circ-90^\circ=60^\circ$$

$$\angle HPN= 180^\circ-150^\circ=30^\circ$$
$$\angle HNM= 180^\circ-120^\circ=60^\circ$$

With these angles in mind I proceeded to calculate the lengths by using the formula $L=\theta\times R$

The first radius is calculated directly as is the same as the length of the wire thus is $21\,\textrm{inches}$.

$$R_{1}=21$$

The second radius is calculated as the difference between the 9 inches of the right wall which is on the back of the spoon and the total 21, hence the acting radius will be:

$$R_{2}=21-9=12$$

The third radius same as the previous one, will be the difference between those acting 12 inches and the other 9 inches from the base of the spoon becoming:

$$R_{3}=12-9=3$$

The the last step will be just replacing those ones with the angles already found as (taken into consideration transforming the sexagesimal angles in radians):

$$L_{1}=\theta \times R=(60^\circ\times\frac{\pi}{180^{\circ}})\times 21=7\pi$$

$$L_{2}=\theta \times R=(30^\circ\times\frac{\pi}{180^{\circ}})\times 12=2\pi$$

$$L_{3}=\theta \times R=(60^\circ\times\frac{\pi}{180^{\circ}})\times 3=1\pi$$

Hence the total distance would be the sum of each distance:

$$\textrm{Distance traveled}=7\pi + 2\pi + \pi= 10 \pi$$

Would this approach be okay?. I'm not very sure if my assumptions are correct as I'm just assuming that the structure is leveled with the ground and forming parallel lines.

Comment: Wasn't there anything said about the sphere's size?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician No, sorry. The problem omitted that information.

Comment: You might surmise why I asked about it. If the sphere was sufficiently sizable, your last arc will be a bit short of $60^\circ$. If the sphere is negligibly small, that $60^\circ$ would be fine.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Why would it be shorter?.

Comment: If the sphere bumps into the last wall, its center point would not be touching the wall, but would be slightly offset from it. If all you had was a string with a heavy end, you'd be able to cover the full $60^\circ$

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Good observation I completely missed that part. If that would had been the case how do I calculate that angle?. What it comes to my mind might be using the cosines law to find the angle between the center and the bigger radius formed before the wire touches the third wall and after finding that angle then I differentiate this result and the $60^\circ$.